# Is there a way to force Perl to always use the latest version?

Tags: perl

This is in relation to this question: [Why doesn't Perl use latest version by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244437/why-doesnt-perl-use-latest-version-by-default)

I'm aware that I can force it with `use v5.14` from within a script, and that's what I'm currently doing, but I'd like to force the interpreter itself to use the latest version by default.

Whether or not this is a *good* idea is not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pragma when running `perl` like this:

```
perl -Mv5.14 my_script.pl
```

To use all features of the actual `perl` installed, this should work:

```
perl -M"feature ':all'" my_script.pl
```

Comment: So what I would do is go into /usr/bin/perl and replace the perl executable with a shell script that prepends "-Mv5.14" then calls the perl executable?

Comment: You could. I don't think it's a good idea though. The system `perl` command is used by many system programs and they might be confused if you changed it.